# English error messages in JSF 2.0.3 (not validation)?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss6.x, faces-config

I had configured JSF 1.2 successfully to display English error messages that come from the server. Now I was making the transition to JSF 2.0, but the error messages seem to be back to German. Localized error messages are a real pain if you want to google up anything (I have no idea who decided localized error messages to be a good thing BTW!).

Here's the **faces-config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

  <application>
    <!-- view handler only for JSF 1.2 -->
    <!--view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler-->

    <locale-config>
      <default-locale>en</default-locale>
      <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
      <supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
  </application>

</faces-config>
```

I'm using JSF 2.0.3 as shipped with JBAS 6, plus Seam and RichFaces.

Does anyone know how to get error messages in English language? Maybe config from the deployer or JBAS 6 itself?

Edit: the error messages appear at server startup as launched from inside Eclipse.

Comment: _"I have no idea who decided localized error messages to be a good thing BTW!"_ This must have been the guys who want to make everything user friendly ;-)

Comment: And then someday: "Please send in the error message you get!" - "Okay here's my error message in Chinese" :-O *scnr* ;-)

Comment: This depends whether you are a user or a developer ... But easy switching of language is a great feature and jsf supports that. BTW My locale configuration is similar to yours. Are you sure that you don't switch locale programmatically?

Comment: I haven't touched anything concerning locales in my webappar but that setting in the faces config. All other error messages coming from Hiberate or Seam are in English. Some however, I'm not sure whether they belong to JSF, are mixed-language. Example: "WARNUNG [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal" Notice the **U**. This message however appears directly underneath a JSF INFO, so I'm not sure here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message comes from your container, not from JSF.

You can change your regional settings or add the JVM parameter -Duser.language=en when you start the container.