# Facelets and local debug error message language

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, localization, facelets

I'm trying to create an application using JSF and primefaces. When I made my project a maven project and added primefaces I started getting some localized error messages. This is bad for me since it makes the problem much harder to google.

I had a look at: [English error messages in JSF 2.0.3 (not validation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250519/english-error-messages-in-jsf-2-0-3-not-validation)

But changeing the regional settings of Glassfish does not affect the language used in these errors. And only some errors seem to be localized.

Example:

```
FATAL:   JSF1073: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException caught during processing of RESTORE_VIEW 1 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 11] Referensen till enhet "s" måste avslutas med ';'-avgränsare.
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to change this so that the message will be in english?

Comment: To be clear: you've set LC_*, LANG or used `-Duser.language=en` as a JVM argument, so `Locale.getDefault()` actually returns an english locale?

Comment: No, I interpreted 'container' to mean Glassfish, so I changed it's setting using the admin pages.

Comment: Maybe that explains the mix between languages. What happens if you restart Glassfish with the `-Duser.language=en` JVM argument?

Comment: I have only interacted with Glassfish through Netbeans or through the browser, so I'm not sure what that means. Do you mean starting Glassfish using 'asadmin'?

Comment: [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gepzd.html) say you can do that with `create-jvm-options` command of asadmin. Sorry, never used Glassfish, so I just can point to the docs.

Comment: Are you running GlassFish from inside Eclipse? In that case you need to alter Eclipse's own locale settings instead. Let me know is that's true, then I'll post a detailed answer.

Comment: @BalusC : No, I'm using Netbeans.

Comment: The same story applies to Netbeans. I only can't tell the exact setting off top of head.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. I tried changeing the locale settings for Netbeans and it didn't work. Also, most messages are in english (what I want), and very few in swedish (which I don't want), which have to do with using JSF somehow, which makes me think it is some more specific setting somewhere that has to be changed.