# WildFly 20: error messages coming in non-English language (Eclipse Servers view)

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, wildfly

I'm running a fairly simple JSF webapp using multi-language.

faces-config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
                  version="2.3">
        
        <application>
        
            <locale-config>
                <default-locale>de_DE</default-locale>
                <supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
                <supported-locale>de_DE</supported-locale>
            </locale-config>
            
        ...
```

I keep getting error messages like:

```
20:58:38,570 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-1) JSF1073: javax.faces.convert.ConverterException erfasst während Verarbeitung von RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=team-member-table-form:table:0:j_idt118: Could not convert '1976-03-03' to a string.
20:58:38,571 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-1) team-member-table-form:table:0:j_idt118: Could not convert '1976-03-03' to a string.: javax.faces.convert.ConverterException: team-member-table-form:table:0:j_idt118: Could not convert '1976-03-03' to a string.
    at javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter.getAsString(DateTimeConverter.java:551)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getFormattedValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:491)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getFormattedValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:509)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:330)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:143)
```

^^ "ConverterException erfasst während Verarbeitung von RENDER_RESPONSE ..." and then "Could not convert..."
OR

```
15:10:50,902 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-20) JSF1064: Ressource touch/touchswipe.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.
15:10:50,903 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-20) : java.io.IOException: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
```

I found my own question from 10 years ago at [English error messages in JSF 2.0.3 (not validation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250519/english-error-messages-in-jsf-2-0-3-not-validation)

...but the solution to add `-Duser.language=en` to the launcher doesn't work.

Any chance anybody knows how to get **English** error messages at all times on WildFly, because googling them in German or any other non-English language doesn't make any sense?

Changing the default JSF locale to "en_US" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your locale:

- for example you can export LANG="en_US.UTF-8" in the shell script that launch the server
- pass the following parameters in the java launch command -Duser.region=US -Duser.language=en adding them to the JAVA_OPTS

Comment: I'm not using a shell script to start the server, at least not locally. I'm using the Eclipse built-in UI (Servers view). As such, I'm using the launch configuration there, which allows passing -D args as well, but they **don't** work. (added Eclipse info to question)

Comment: You can set environment variables on you server runtime in eclipse so you could set the LANG couldn't you ?

Comment: I'm really surprised there as I use that 'trick' to build Wildfly given that I'm not on a US_en OS.